# How do I "pop in", aka undo the Pop Out feature on Outlook when composing a reply?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

When you draft a reply in Outlook, there's a `Pop Out` feature that lets you windowize your message. But there doesn't seem to be any obvious undo. Is this just an oversight that was missed or am I blind to some obvious button?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option in Outlook to compose a Reply (a) in its own Windows, or (b) in line with the Outlook Main window.

Once chosen by the option, then that is fixed (does not change back and forth) until the option is changed again.

If you are drafting a Reply and need to postpone finishing the Reply, just close it, and it will save in Drafts (you will be asked to confirm) until ready to complete it.

You can delete the draft if you do not wish to continue.

[image]

Comment: Agree with John, there may be no option to undo it after you pop out the window. Just save it in your draft folder and your message wouldn't be lost.